# Is there a way to control scope of fontspec font change?

Tags: xetex, fontspec, grouping

I would like to limit the scope of `\fontspec` to just one or a couple of words in my paragraph, for example:

```
Vivamus gravida lacus a sapien \fontspec{The Font Name}{interdum} eget 
interdum mi sodales. Aenean nisi nunc, feugiat a auctor sed, consectetur
ut elit. In id tellus ac lectus ullamcorper tempor
```

If I just want to change the font of the word *interdum*, what would be the correct way to do it?

(I'm using XeLaTeX under Mac OS X 10.7.2)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use braces to create a group:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}

Vivamus gravida lacus a sapien {\fontspec{Arial}interdum} eget
interdum mi sodales. Aenean nisi nunc, feugiat a auctor sed, consectetur
ut elit. In id tellus ac lectus ullamcorper tempor
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

As an addition to Ulrike’s answer:

You could specify a new font family with `\newfontfamily` and then make a matching `\text…` command:

```
\newfontfamily\arial[⟨font features⟩]{Arial}
\newcommand*{\textal}[1]{{\arial #1}}
```

and use it like this

```
Vivamus gravida lacus a sapien \textal{interdum} eget
interdum mi sodales. Aenean nisi nunc, feugiat a auctor sed, consectetur
ut elit. In id tellus ac lectus ullamcorper tempor
```

<sub>fontspec manual section 6, p. 8.</sub>