# Changing Hebrew fonts with cjhebrew?

Tags: hebrew

I'm using the cjhebrew package. How can I change the Hebrew font used while still keeping a 12pt Times English font? According to http://sites.huji.ac.il/tex/newlatex_usage.txt, there are many Hebrew fonts, as it states:

- Jerusalem (used as default font)
- Dead Sea (used as bold font)
- Tel-Aviv (used as sans-serif or typewriter font)
- Old Jaffa (used as italic or slanted font and for emphasize)
- Hebrew classic normal and slanted (command \textclas)
- Shalom Old Style (command \textshold)
- Shalom Script (command \textshscr)
- Shalom Stick (command \textshstk)
- Carmel normal and slanted (command \textcrml)
- Frank Ruehl normal, bold and slanted (command \textfr)
- Redis normal, bold and slanted (command \textredis)

Is there a way to change it? Also, is there another/better package I might be using?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732419/changing-hebrew-fonts-with-cjhebrew?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use XeTeX for writing Hebrew (and just about everything else).  With fontspec, changing fonts is quite straightforward.  See [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35271/is-there-a-way-to-control-scope-of-fontspec-font-change) question and the [fontspec documentation](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/xetex/latex/fontspec/) for more info.